# difference between my and our ? (declared in the same file)

Tags: perl

Before writing this program,I thought that `our` is a package scope variable and `my` is
a file scope variable.But,After did that program,I am get confused.

My program is,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package one; 
our $val = "sat";
my $new = "hello";
print "ONE:val =>$val \n";
print "ONE:new =>$new \n\n";

package two;
print "TWO:val =>$val \n";
print "TWO:new =>$new \n";
```

which outputs

```
ONE:val =>sat 
ONE:new =>hello 

TWO:val =>sat 
TWO:new =>hello
```

So,what is the difference between `my` and `our`.Whether the both are the same or it having any difference?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding *(declared in the same file)* in the title because i think that is the kernel of the question ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you see, both `my` and `our` have lexical effect.

`my` creates a lexically scoped variable.

`our` creates a lexically scoped ***alias*** to a package variable.

Just because you say `package` in no fashion changes the lexical scope, so your `$val` is still an alias to `$one::val` even after having seen the `package two` statement.

If you don’t see a close curly, you haven’t finished your scope. (Or EOF or end of string in a string `eval`).

Comment: @aleroot: check out the profile of [tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist). I think you can trust his word

Comment: Thank you very much..Now I understood the difference between them.

Comment: very interesting, I would have expected `package` to end the scope. Now I know. +1

Comment: @JoelBerger `package NAME;` neither introduces nor closes a scope, although it is itself a lexically scoped declaration. The super-recent `package NAME {BLOCK}` syntax does, though, but it uses braces for that purpose, just as everything else in Perl does.

Comment: Before `package NAME { ... }`, one could use `{ package NAME; ... }`.

Comment: It so bothers me that `package NAME { ... }` doesn't execute the block as a BEGIN. oo!!! I'll write a plugin to do that! Easy peasy. Maybe I'll use a different keyword (`module`? `inlined_module`?) and set `%INC` too! Don't mind my ramblings :D

Answer (score 6):

**my** restrict the variables access to the innermost block in which
they were declared. If there is no block, they are file-scoped.

**our** instead associates a
simple name with a package variable in the current package , so it is declared at the package level and linked to the package name. **our** tries to help out by letting you use package variables without adding the package name.

```
package pack;
our $variable;    # These are the same
$pack::variable;  # These are the same
```

An **our** variable is something similar to C's static variable, but is different because the variable declared with **our** in a function is still accessible outside the function if it is called with the variable's fully qualified name.

But most of all **my** is lexically scoped while **our** is lexical scope but their life persistent even outside the declaring block(their life is like global variable life), therefore to really understand the difference between **my** and **our** you have to understand the difference between lexically and global scoped in Perl.

So briefly the difference between the two type are :

### Global variables

Any code, anywhere, can change their values.

### Lexical variables

The life of the variable end with the the end of the code block in with they are included, after that their values are garbage collected. These kind of variables can be accessed only within the block in which they are declared.

---

**To answer you specific example-question :** *try to move the second package declaration (package two) into another file, and you will see the difference between **my** and **our** ...*

Comment: I understood the difference.And Thank you for given a good explanation.

Comment: This is just wrong. `our` declarations are *not* global - only the package variable is. `perl -Mstrict -e "our $x = 1; { our $y = 2; }; print $x; print $y"` says `Global symbol "$y" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.`

Comment: Yes if you declare an our variable in a block you can't access it outside the block ... but its life doesn't end when the block ends ... Take a look [here][http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_our.htm] : An our declaration declares a global variable that will be visible across its entire lexical scope ...

Comment: Package variables are global (i.e. visible everywhere when properly qualified), but the variables created by `our` (i.e. lexically-scoped aliases to package variables) are not.

Comment: Yes but they live as a global variable.

Comment: `our` variables are not destroyed, if that is what you mean. But *"`my` is lexically scoped while `our` is global scope"* is wrong as they both have identical scope.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to distinguish between *visibility* and *lifetime*.

The *visibility* of variables declared using `our` or `my` is identical. You can used the name anywhere after the declaration before the first enclosing brace or end of file.

Beware that this doesn't apply to *full-qualified* variable names, which need no declaration and can be accessed anywhere. Without declaring anything I can assign to a package variable

```
$pack::three = 3;
```

and use that anywhere else in any package. I don't even have to declare the `pack` package. But if I write

```
package pack;
our $three;
```

I have generated an shortened *alias* for `$pack::three` that I can use within the same lexical scope as I could a `my` variable in the same place: before an enclosing brace or end of file.

These package variables are always available from the start of the program's execution. Just like hash elements you can always assign to a new one and it will always be there - their *lifetime* is endless. In fact package variables *are* hash elements to all intents and purposes.

Lexical variables, declared with `my`, on the other hand, are created at the point of declaration and destroyed once they go out of scope and there is no reference to them held anywhere. So, unless you take the reference of such a variable, its *lifetime* is the same as its *visibility*. A `my` declaration inside a loop causes a new variable to be created and destroyed for each execution the loop.

In your code, you have created an alias `$val` for package variable `$one::val` and a lexical variable `$new`. Neither are within a code block so both are visible to the end of the file. The `package two` has no effect at all here, but if you had written `our $val` *after* that second package statement you would have changed the alias `$val` to indicate `$two::val` instead.

I hope that helps.